# np.subtract along an axis

Tags: python, numpy, subtraction

Is there an easy way to subtract along the axis of 2-D array?

```
a=np.array([[610,550],[400,360]])
np.sum(a,axis=0) # Results in  array([1010, 910])

np.subtract(a[0],a[1]) # Results in array([210, 190])
np.subtract(a,axis=0) # Errors out obviously
```

Comment: `np.subtract` is like `np.add`, not `np.sum`

Comment: IMHO, `np.subtract(a[0], a[1])` is simple enough

Comment: Perhaps you want `np.diff(a, axis=0)`?

Answer (score 2):

`np.subtract` subtracts the corresponding elements of two arrays. Subtraction of two arrays along an axis is meaningless, since it happens to each element regardless of its position relative to its neighbors. Notice that in your example, `np.sum` only accepts one array, not two.

To find the differences between successive elements of a single array, use `np.diff`, which accepts an `axis` argument exactly as you would expect

```
np.diff(a, axis=0)
```

You can manually implement `diff` by calling subtract on an array sliced as `1:` and `:-1` along the desired axis. In your example:

```
a[1:] - a[:-1]
```